# Log4j2 sometimes gets stuck when reconfiguring it

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

In an application in which we are using Log42J2 2.19.0, we initially use a very
simple config for the beginning of the server's start up, which has the standard
`log4j2.xml` name and is picked up automatically by Log4J2. Somewhat later during
the start up, we need to reconfigure Log4J2 with a different config. For that
we do [as suggested in the Log4j2 docs](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.4/faq.html#reconfig_from_code):

```java
final LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
// force a reconfiguration
context.setConfigLocation(log4jConfigFile.toURI());
```

This usually works, but sometimes (and with a frequency enough to be an annoyance) it gets stuck, which means we need to kill the server (or the node, when in a cluster) and try again.

When I tried debugging, I found it is stuck looping inside `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.waitForCompletion()`.
It is waiting for a log event to finish, or rather, it is waiting for
`afterLogEvent` to be called, which is the one that should decrease the `counter`
variable, but this apparently never happens, and the counter simply stays at 1,
causing the infinite loop.

And here is as far as I got. Is there anything I'm missing for the reconfiguration? Is some previous check or precondition required before attempting to reconfigure? Or is this some Log4J2 concurrency bug?

Comment: would you mind [creating a Log4j ticket](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug_report.md) with sufficient context, please? Providing a trimmed down reproduction path would help greatly.

Comment: Will do so, thanks! I don't have yet a simple reproduction, which is also what's making it harder, but will mention it in the ticket if I manage to find one.

Comment: Opened an issue: https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/issues/1399

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer my own question as I managed to find the source of the issue causing this.

We had an `StackOverflowError` caused by some Spring AOP advice, and this was getting masked most of the time (the exception would show up in some systems, but not all of them). Spring was catching `Throwable` and continuing execution, so the server managed to start up and usually work without issues. Sometimes though, the `StackOverflowError` would cause a Log4J2 `finally` block to not run properly, leaving Log4J2 in an invalid state where it thought there was some other thread logging something and was waiting for that to finish, when there was no such thread (a `counter` variable that had to be decremented in a `finally` block wasn't being decremented). This is because a [StackOverflowError can cause a finally block to be bypassed](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8177802).